# open GL installation

Tags: software-installation, ati, steam, opengl

hi guys i tried to launch stean game dota 2 from ubuntu, and i got this error

[image]

how can i install it? // Im kinda new to ubuntu sorry for bothering tnx in advanc

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X]
   Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Device e214
   Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: i don`t get any output if i type that in terminal,i c/p lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

Comment: You probably type it with errors. Just copy and paste it. If it still does not give output, just post `lspci` to start with.

Comment: !https://scontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t35.0-12/12197251_10206640067614571_855773531_o.jpg?oh=0c54bf187293dc07c4f78a1c262addd3&oe=5639BC71

Comment: You missed the last qoute. Press Ctrl+C and try again.

Comment: And please do not post pictures. Copy text. And also you can copy and paste the command.

Comment: sorry about that,still don`t understand what i missed,can u write in comment what should i copy again plz

Comment: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X]
 Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Device e214
 Kernel driver in use: radeon

Comment: You ran this command `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D`, but I asked to run `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`. Do you see the difference?

Comment: I also asked to [edit] your question and post the output there...

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a proprietary AMD driver.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

and reboot.

Comment: tnx for help and ur patience